# Автозаполнение кнопками области

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

есть UI-панель, на которой создаются кнопки с текстом, идея в том, чтобы спавнить кнопки друг за другом, а когда не хватает места в строке, переходить на новую, размер(ширина) кнопки подстраивается под длину текста при помощи horizontal layout group и content size fitter, но content size fitter блокирует у кнопки width, поэтому я не могу использовать его, чтобы написать скрипт расчета позиции новой кнопки. Встроенный функционал юнити не подходит: horizontal layout group хорошо спавнит кнопки друг за дружкой и они правильного размера, но это работает только в одну строку, grid layout group задает фиксированный размер кнопки сам. Я так понимаю, тут только писать все-все самому или есть какое-то решение? Нижу визуальный пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]